# Adding methods to QFile - compile error "Undefined reference to ..."

Tags: qt

I would like to add a method to QFile called chkFileExists().  I have the following code files for extending QFile:

mvqfile.h

```
#ifndef MVQFILE_H
#define MVQFILE_H

#include <QFile>

class MVQFile : public QFile
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MVQFile(QObject *parent = 0);
    bool chkFileExists(const QString &file);
};

#endif // MVQFILE_H
```

mvqfile.cpp

```
#include "mvqfile.h"
#include <QFileInfo>

MVQFile::MVQFile(QObject *parent) :
    QFile(parent)
{
}

bool chkFileExists(const QString &file)
{
    QFile ff(file);
    QFileInfo fileInfo(ff);
    return (fileInfo.exists() && fileInfo.isFile());
}
```

Then in my main bit of code I have:

```
#include "mvqfile.h"


MVQFile file;
file.setFileName("/home/path/filename.csv");

if (file.chkFileExists(file.fileName()))
{
  qDebug() << file.fileName() << " exists";
} else {
  qDebug() << file.fileName() << " does not exist";
}
```

When compiled I get the error:

```
"undefined reference to `MVQFile :: chkFileExists(QString const&) ' "
```

Why?  It seems correct to me.

Comment: As a sidenote, why `chkFileExists` is an instance method yet it takes a file name as an argument? Also omitting `ec` to save two characters out of 15 on method name is weird.

Comment: Good points.  The first has happened as I have just moved this function into the class and forgot. Now fixed. The second is a personal preference thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the namespace to your function definition. It should be:

```
bool MVQFile::chkFileExists(const QString &file) {

}
```